# Swap 2 dimensional array key order using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$array[a][1]=value11
$array[a][2]=value12
$array[a][3]=value13
$array[b][2]=value22
$array[c][3]=value33
```

I need to change it as

```
$array[1][a]=value11
$array[2][a]=value12
$array[3][a]=value13
$array[2][b]=value22
$array[3][c]=value33
```

I can do it using foreach

```
foreach($array as $k1=>$array2)
{
   foreach($array2 as $k2=>$value)
   {
     $new_array[$k2][$k1]=$value;
   }
}
```

is there any simple function to do it in single line?

Thanks

Comment: Probably one of `array_map` or `array_walk`, but then you're just replacing your loop with a closure.

Comment: You can create a function with those `foreach` loops and then calling that function will only require a single line. What do people have against more than 1 line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't have a native simple function to achieve this kind of purpose in one line.But if you want a one line function you could wrap your code inside a function and call it simply each time you will need it :

```
function swapKeys($array){
    if(!is_array($array)) return false;
    foreach($array as $k1=>$array2)
    {   
        if(!is_array($array2)) return false;
        foreach($array2 as $k2=>$value)
        {
            $new_array[$k2][$k1]=$value;
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

However if you don't want to use `foreach` loops there is also an alternative with `array_map` or `array_walk` which make use  of many of native PHP arrays functions like `array_keys` ,`array_combine` but also the concept of closure and scope variable inheritance.So your one line code could look like:

```
!($new=[])?array_map(function($val,$key)use(&$new){$new+=array_combine(array_keys($val),array_map(function($value)use($key){ return [$key=>$value];},$val));},$array,array_keys($array)):[];
```

or

```
!($new=[])?array_walk($array, function($item,$key) use (&$new){ $new+=array_combine(array_keys($item),array_map(function($val) use($key){return [$key=>$val];},$item));}):[];
```

Given the array :

```
 $array['a'][1]='value11';
    $array['a'][2]='value12';
    $array['a'][3]='value13';
    $array['b'][4]='value14';
    $array['c'][5]='value15';
```

`var_dump($new)` will output in the two cases:

```
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(7) "value11"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(7) "value12"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(7) "value13"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["b"]=>
    string(7) "value14"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["c"]=>
    string(7) "value15"
  }
}
```

You can check the working code online https://3v4l.org/K4VRu